# Cannot disable word warp on table responsive tbody

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

so i having some weird behaviour that i recently just experienced, i have a table that i want it to responsive (showing scrollbar when the table width is exceeding screen width)

But i don't want the cell inside the table to be warped, so i try to add `text-nowarp` that simply just do `white-space:nowarp;` and it works for the table header in `thead` but i don;t know why it just not working in `tbody` or `tr` or `td` or even i add `span` inside `td`

here is my code in general

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr class="text-nowarp">
        <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
        <th>sit consectetu</th>
        <th>consectetur adipisicing</th>
        <th>adipisicing</th>
        <th>Lorem</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="text-nowarp" style="white-space:nowarp;"> 
      <tr>
        <td class="text-nowarp"><span class="text-nowarp" style="white-space:nowarp;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Odit exercitationem non quibusdam explicabo repellendus iure natus expedita, illum, possimus veritatis aspernatur inventore ad itaque. Eveniet consequatur cum modi nostrum animi?</span></td>

        <td class="text-nowarp" style="white-space:nowarp;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam deserunt earum ullam ea dolores rerum veniam eius voluptatum eligendi odio quis maxime, numquam laborum quaerat quo optio illum atque dolore.</td>

        <td class="text-nowarp" style="white-space:nowarp;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse voluptates nobis vel veniam autem magni laborum placeat porro eum magnam fugit ipsum aliquam maxime beatae, omnis molestiae quasi nesciunt nemo?</td>

        <td class="text-nowarp" style="white-space:nowarp;">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore a facere aliquid at id? Neque, rerum assumenda! Cumque officia voluptatum exercitationem impedit error, placeat labore. Aperiam, saepe. Impedit, eligendi nam?</td>

        <td class="text-nowarp" style="white-space:nowarp;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate nobis eveniet quo asperiores aperiam! Sit beatae necessitatibus quae, explicabo quaerat blanditiis minima nulla iure voluptates dicta consectetur adipisci recusandae vel?</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It's got to be `nowrap`. *Warping* isn't part of CSS yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just misspelled. You need not `text-nowarp` but `text-nowrap`and not `style="white-space:nowarp;` but `style="white-space:nowrap;`

Comment: Problems that are based on a simple typo should be **closed**, not **answered** as keeping this on the platform is of no value to anyone.